# How to validating form in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, antd

I am working on project in reactjs, I implemented some validation in form. I implemented a logic if someone click on next without uploading photo and video then display error to user , validation is working fine in first attempt it working but when user delete a photo or video then click on next the form is not validating  . Could you please help me how to validate form I am using ant-design form I will share code with you please help me i am really stuck

[Please View Image of Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVSN3.png)

**Code**

```
 <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <FormItem>
        {getFieldDecorator('picture', {
          rules: [
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'Please upload picture!',
            },
          ],
        })(
          <Dragger {...props}>
            <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
              <Icon type="upload" />
            </p>
            <p className="ant-upload-text">
              Click or drag photo to this area to upload
            </p>
          </Dragger>,
        )}
      </FormItem>

      <PhotoText>Select a Video to Upload</PhotoText>
      <FormItem>
        {getFieldDecorator('video', {
          rules: [
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'Please upload video!',
            },
          ],
        })(
          <Dragger>
          <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
            <Icon type="upload" />
          </p>
          <p className="ant-upload-text">
            Click or drag Video to this area to upload
          </p>
        </Dragger>,
        )}
      </FormItem>
    </Form>
```

Comment: Please help me ?

Comment: Can you please add your submit function too or create a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)?

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani. Actually I am working on Wizard Form .
{current < this.steps.length - 1 && (
                  <Button
                    type="primary"
                    htmlType="submit"
                    style={{
                      background: '#ff9700',
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                      border: 'none',
                      float: 'right',
                    }}
                  >
                    Next <Icon type="right" />
                  </Button>
                )}

Comment: Thank You please help me it really urgent . We have some deadline that's why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you are using wizard form so you need to pass `this.props.form` in each steps as given below:

```
<Step1 form={this.props.form} />
```

And then in `next()`, you can use [`validateFieldsAndScroll`](https://ant.design/components/form/#validateFields/validateFieldsAndScroll) to check for the validation as given below:

```
next() {
    if (this.state.current == 0) {
        this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll(["picture"], (err, values) => {
            if (!err) {
                const current = this.state.current + 1;
                this.setState({ current });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have created a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/kx8wo2953).

**Edit**

Then, you need to write your own logic in some way because I don't think Ant-design provides such functionality. For example, instead of `if (!err)` you can write as follows:

```
if (!err && values.picture && values.picture.fileList.length > 0)
```

And then you can write some logic to display custom validation message as:

```
{picture && picture.fileList.length <= 0 ? "Please upload picture!" : ""}
```

Please check the [updated demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/x2qoyr696o).

Comment: it doesnt work, if user uploads and then deletes the picture the form indeed goes to next step isntead of displaying error message and staying in current step

Comment: @NikosM. yes Validation is already implemented but when user delete image it going to next

Comment: @NikosM. Could you please help me

Comment: @NikosM. Updated the answer.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani Thank You it working , please also have a look to this question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631198/how-to-preview-a-video-in-reactjs )

Comment: @Jon I don't think ant-design supports that feature.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani please have a look to this question .  Urgent need  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645205/how-to-change-step-number-with-loading-icon-in-reactjsplease