# How to preview a video in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am working on project in ReactJS, Currently I am using ant-design for file uploading. I want to preview video when user select a video . I am new to reactjs and unable to complete my task. Could someone please help me how it would be possible to preview a video . I will share my code with you You may check my code . Thanks

**Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './styletwo.css';
import { Form, Upload, Button, Icon } from 'antd';
// import reqwest from 'reqwest';
const Dragger = Upload.Dragger;

const FormItem = Form.Item;
const PhotoText = styled.div`
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2rem 0 1rem 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: -webkit-auto;
`;

const props = {
  action: '',
  listType: 'picture',
};
class RegisterStepTwo extends React.Component {


  render() {

    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <PhotoText>Select a Photo to Upload</PhotoText>
          <FormItem>
            {getFieldDecorator('picture', {
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please upload picture!',
                },
              ],
            })(
              <Dragger {...props}>
                <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
                  <Icon type="upload" />
                </p>
                <p className="ant-upload-text">
                  Click or drag photo to this area to upload
                </p>
              </Dragger>,
            )}
          </FormItem>

          <PhotoText>Select a Video to Upload</PhotoText>
          <FormItem>
            {getFieldDecorator('video', {
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please upload video!',
                },
              ],
            })(
              <Dragger>
              <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
                <Icon type="upload" />
              </p>
              <p className="ant-upload-text">
                Click or drag Video to this area to upload
              </p>
            </Dragger>,
            )}
          </FormItem>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default RegisterStepTwo;
```

Comment: you can use https://video-react.js.org/ package and pass props for a show video when user select video

Comment: @HarshShah If you have video or guaidlance it would be helpful

Comment: you want to show video when the user upload it or after the uploading complete they select one video then you want to show to them?

Comment: No, I want to show video when user select it before uploading

Comment: you can check out this example for image https://codepen.io/hartzis/pen/VvNGZP     you can do same thing for video also

Comment: I did code for image preview but now stuck in video

Answer (score 7):

Considering you have your video file in a state:

```
    const [videoFile, setVideoFile] = useState();
```

You can use `createObjectUrl` directly in JSX:

```
<video width="400" controls>
    <source src={URL.createObjectURL(videoFile)}/>
</video>
```

Comment: Perfect answers!

Answer (score 1):

First read blob data from your file

```
let reader = new FileReader();

//if reading completed
reader.onload = e => {
     let blobData = e.target.result); //blob data
     console.log(blobData);
};

//read the file
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Once read as blob you can use html5 video tag to show the video like following

```
<video width="400" controls>
     <source src={blobData} type={fileType}/>
     Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Please have a look to my crude CodeSandBox 
https://codesandbox.io/s/wq2jnm9wpk

I hope this would help you.

Comment: Hi, I clicked and the CodeSandBox is giving error: Error
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `PreviewVideoAntdUpload`.