# How to change Step number with Loading Icon in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am working on project in reactjs, Currently I am using `Ant-design` for Wizard form. I will share ant-design link. I want to change step number with loading icon when user click on next.. The current step number ( for example 1 ) is changed to loading and proceed to next step . I am beginner could you please help me ?

**Ant-Design Link:** [Ant-design](https://ant.design/components/steps/#header)

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani Please click on `Ant-design link ` I used same code

Comment: There you may see `Switch Step`

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani I want to achieve when user click on next the current step number change to loading icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using steps [custom icon](https://ant.design/components/steps/#Steps.Step) property. The idea is you can pass the `key` in `steps` as given below:

```
const steps = [
  {
    title: "First",
    content: "First-content",
    key: 1
  },
  {
    title: "Second",
    content: "Second-content",
    key: 2
  },
  {
    title: "Last",
    content: "Last-content",
    key: 3
  }
];
```

And then you can use `Icon` of type `loading` in condition to check if `current+1 === key` as given below:

```
<Step
    key={item.title}
    title={item.title}
    icon={item.key !== 1 && item.key === current+1 ? <Icon type="loading" /> : ""}
/>
```

You can check the [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/j2xkk6yv95).

Comment: By Default step will be 1 when user click on next, the step number changed to loading

Comment: we are close but I mean to say that I want to show loading in current step when user click on next . let me explain  for example currently we are in step 1 When we click on next the current step of number `1` is changed to `Loading Icon`. As your current demo the loading icon is showing in next step but i want that in current step

Comment: It now loading previous step .. I want to load current step when user click on next and move to next step the loading icon will be hide

Comment: bro please have a look to this question and help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53650271/how-to-remove-video-preview-when-user-click-on-delete-in-reactjs

Comment: @Jon I think you need to provide a demo code because it needs more details.

Comment: @triyungi Could you please guide me how I can change the default button style when user click on next ?

Comment: @Jon Which kind of style you want?