# How to Remove Video Preview When User click on Delete in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am working on project in reactjs, Currently I am using `ant-design` form for selection of video and I implemented some logic when user click on video then display video to below but when user click on delete button and select another one the preview video is not remove with delete button . I will share my code please review it and Please help me

Thanks

**Code**

```
<PhotoText>Select a Video to Upload</PhotoText>
      <FormItem>
        {getFieldDecorator('video', {
          rules: [
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'Please upload video!',
            },
          ],
        })(
          <Dragger onChange={this.onChange} accept="video/*">
          <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
            <Icon type="upload" />
          </p>
          <p className="ant-upload-text">
            Click or drag Video to this area to upload
          </p>
        </Dragger>,
        )}
        { this.state.video ? <video width="350" height="280" style={{width:'450px',marginLeft:'23px'}} src={this.state.video} controls/>  : null }
      </FormItem>
```

Comment: Can you create a demo for that?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/new, choose react and do a demo